# JFreeChart hiding (some) x axis values

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm currently using JFreeChart to create a line chart. This line chart gets updated every second with a new value (currently a random value). This way you can see how your data has changed over a certain time period. However after I've added over ten values they don't fit on the line anymore turning into dots. I would like to only have 5 values shown at a time which are spread across the entire timings. This is how it looks now:
[image]

Notice the dots at the bottom of the chart. I would like it to be changed to this:
[image]
Note that I want to keep all points which are created between these points in time. So data from 11:31:00, 11:31:01, 11:31:02 etc. should be still there.

This is what I currently have:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();

category = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
category.addValue(new Random().nextInt(10), "Data", date.getHour() + ":" + date.getMinute() + ":" + date.getSecond());

chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Values", "Time", "Data", category, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
((NumberAxis) ((CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot()).getRangeAxis()).setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by using a TimeSeriesChart. This is what I ended up with:

```
TimeSeriesCollection collection = new TimeSeriesCollection();
TimeSeries serie = new TimeSeries("Data");
collection.addSeries(serie);

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Data", "Time", "Data", collection, false, true, false);
```